# Parsing a API source, but the JSON souse is not updating (Cache?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rake

I have coded a rake file to monitor and fetch data from a website that has this data in JSON format.  The following is the actual source of this data

https://www.thegazette.co.uk/company/07877158/filings/data.json

The rake file monitors the "total_count" in the above json and when it changes the rake will fetch and save any new information

The issue I have is after the first time it monitors that page, it simply doesn't update.  As a real-world current example, the above json source was updated overnight with two new records, and consequently, the "total_count" increased from 40 to 42, but my rake is still telling me there is 40 (and subsequently doing nothing because it thinks nothing has changed)

I think it is a cache issue but have cleared my rails cache with no success.  It is strange because I don't have this issue with other similar rakes I have created for other sites

My rake code is as follows

```
desc "Monitor"
task :S_01 => :environment do

    require 'rubygems'
    require 'open-uri'
    require 'openssl'

    def g_api(url)
        uri = URI.parse(url)
        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
        request.content_type = "application/json"
        req_options = {
          use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
        }
        response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
          http.request(request)
        end
        data = JSON.parse(response.body)

    end

    company = CompanyBorrower.where(id: 43)

    company.each do |f|

        begin

            #scrape source
            tg_fh_url = "https://www.thegazette.co.uk/company/"+f.ch+"/filings/data.json"
            gf_scrape = g_api(tg_fh_url)

            ch_s = gf_scrape.fetch('total_count', nil) #scrape

            puts ch_s

            if not f.filing_count == ch_s # has teh cound change - if not, skip

                f.update_attributes(cwdetail1: ch_s, filing_update: ch_fh3)

                gf_scrape['items'].first(3).each_with_index do |f1, index|

                    #fetch & save data here

                end

            end

        rescue
            next
        end

    end

end
```

**EDIT**

Added the following to the code, but get an error

```
    response["Cache-Control: no-cache"]
```

> NoMethodError: undefined method `fetch' for nil:NilClass

```
def g_api(url)
    uri = URI.parse(url)
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
    request.content_type = "application/json"
    req_options = {
      use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
    }
    response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
      http.request(request)
    end

    data = JSON.parse(response.body)

    response["Cache-Control: no-cache"]

end
```

Comment: To cut that down the a **Minimal** example, are you saying that `Net::HTTP::Get.new(URI.parse("https://..../company/07877158/filings/..."))` gives you a different result vs accessing that URL from a browser? Perhaps the solution is to provide a `Cache-Control: no-cache` header in the request?

Comment: For full details, see [section 14.9 of the HTTP/1.1 protocol](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

Comment: That is correct - Net::HTTP::Get.new(URI.parse("https://..../company/07877158/filings/...")) gives me a different result vs accessing that URL from a browser.  I've tried adding Cache-Control: no-cache, but get "NoMethodError: undefined method `fetch' for nil:NilClass" (to be clear, apart from the updating issue, it works fine before adding that line) - I've added the edit to my OP

Comment: You need to **set** the `Cache-Control` in the **request**. It's not a *lookup* in the *response*. See the documentation: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Setting+Headers

Comment: Or for instance, you can see some examples of **setting** headers here: https://yukimotopress.github.io/http. Again, don't get mixed up between reading the headers in the response, vs setting the headers in your request.

Comment: It looks like even passing the correct headers gives the same result.  I would suggest to have a look at https://github.com/TheGazette/DevDocs/blob/master/home.md

Comment: Thanks, but I have read through the API literature, but with no success.  I can't work out why this is happening; it is very frustrating.

Comment: This is very annoying - I've looked for an explanation, but no results anywhere!?  Where would the information be stored, and how do I clear it?

Comment: So, randomly, it decided to update.  No idea why, but I know it will continue to be intermittent.  Any further opinions on why this is happening would be appreciated :->

Comment: No more help from anyone? : (